# how to get last inserted id while inserting..but it inserting same the same id..how to resolve this

Tags: laravel-5

controller

i need to insert store_merchant_id from $data..but in my coding it takes only the first id..

```
$data = array(
    'merchant_firstname' => $merchant_firstname,
    'merchant_lastname' => $merchant_lastname,
    'merchant_password' => $merchant_password,
    'merchant_email'=>$merchant_email,                      
);

$merchant_id = Merchant_model::merchant_submit($data);

$data1 = array(
    'store_merchant_id'=>$merchant_id,
    'store_name'=>$store_name,
    'store_phone'=>$store_phone,
    'store_address1'=>$store_address1,
);

$return = Merchant_model::merchant_submit1($data1);
```

Model

```
return DB::table('le_store')->insert($data1);
```

Comment: Could you explain your problem a bit more to help you

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to get the last inserted id and do something with that

So, i am doing the same what you did

**Step 1 : Building the input**

1.

```
$data = array(
    'merchant_firstname' => $merchant_firstname,
    'merchant_lastname' => $merchant_lastname,
    'merchant_password' => $merchant_password,
    'merchant_email'=>$merchant_email,                      
);
```

**Step 2 : Saving the Data**

```
$Merchant = Merchant_model::create($data);
```

**Step 3 : Getting the inserted id**

```
return $Merchant->id;
```

Now the `$Merchant->id`  will have the last inserted id, You shall return or save this to another model that you wish to do.

**Update :**

As you want to update the inserted id to another table, Just do this

As usual like previous

```
$data = array(
    'merchant_firstname' => $merchant_firstname,
    'merchant_lastname' => $merchant_lastname,
    'merchant_password' => $merchant_password,
    'merchant_email'=>$merchant_email,                      
);

$Merchant = Merchant_model::create($data);
```

Then build `$data1`

```
$data1 = array(
    'store_merchant_id'=>$Merchant->id,
    'store_name'=>$store_name,
    'store_phone'=>$store_phone,
    'store_address1'=>$store_address1,
);
```

**Note :**

`store_merchant_id'=>$Merchant->id'` should be like this

Then just create it

```
Merchant_model::create($data1);
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: ErrorException in SiteadminController.php line 1380:
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: $merchant = Merchant_model::merchant_submit($data);
   return $merchant->id;
              $data1=array(
                       'store_merchant_id'=>$merchant->id,

Comment: yes.. 
ErrorException in SiteadminController.php line 1380: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: If you do this `$Merchant = Merchant_model::create($data);` , then can you able to get `$Merchant->id` ?

Comment: here create is the function name.what i do in create at model

Comment: It will create one entry in your table.. You don't have to do anything in your model, Just assign the fillable.

Comment: Could you explain what you need to do, so that i can help you out

Comment: i need to insert merchant id...2 table is there.first table is le_merchant another one is le_store.i want insert here only

Comment: You mean the inserted id to another table ?

Comment: yes.my merchant_id need to  insert  table (le_store) in the field of store_merchant_id..

Comment: sry.now i update your code.but now im getting this error..Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: here one form for the merchant and store.but i need to insert the merchant id to store table.how can u help me

Comment: Error on which part, while inserting data or data1

Comment: We can able to get merchant id right, with that id you should insert in store table.. Can u able to get me ?

Comment: error in controller part $data1..ErrorException in SiteadminController.php line 1382:
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Romba long eh pogudhu.. I can't see your 1382th line.. :( Can you assign like this and `$storeId=>$Merchant->id` print the `$storeId` ?

Comment: Do you have teamviewer ? so that i can solve the problem in few minutes ;)

Comment: like tat only i did...                                                                         $Merchant = Merchant_model::merchant_submit($data);
   $m_id=$Merchant->id;                                         $data1=array('store_merchant_id'=>$m_id,);

Comment: cau u check mail.i wil send u

Comment: Okay, it would be better